# do i have to remove the workers in flask-dramatiq?

Tags: python, dramatiq

the docs only shows how to start but it does not say anything about stopping the workers? is it necessary? if so, how?

I cant seem to find anything to close it
docs: https://flask-dramatiq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: what docs? please give more information about what exactly you are talking about or an example and a link to the docs.

Comment: https://flask-dramatiq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ - here, for task executing/queuing